# Tableau Data Security for Sales Revenue

Tags: tableau-api

I want the salesrep to see both theirs and OVERALL TEAMS PERFORMANCE. Is it possible to create a TOGGLE SWITCH : ME/TEAM...when they click on ME - it shows them their revenue and when they click on TEAM - it show overall team revenue. But, they still shouldn't be able to see other salesman revenue...Thanks

Currently, I'm filtering their access to data by their USERNAME using the FULLNAME() function in Tableau. I'm wondering how would the salesrep be able to see the revenue of the TEAM OVERALL which helps them to compare their performance to the team overall

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, with your current setup, you will only be able to display the active sales reps data. This appears to be a requirement for data security. If you want reps to see the overall team data as well, I would create a second data source with aggregated team data, create a view based on this data and place both views side by side on a dashboard.

After that, you could build in the toggle functionality with [parameter](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/changing-views-using-parameters.html) controls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a parameter. Simple example would be a text input that accepts two values, ME or TEAM. For this example, let's call the parameter Parameter 1.
2. Set up a conditional calculated field to handle your data security. The condition is based on the parameter. For this example, let's call the calculated field `What To Show`.
3. Add a filter, preferably at the data source, for What To Show = True.

The code for What To Show is 
`if [Parameter 1] = "ME" then [USERNAME] = FULLNAME() END`

[USERNAME] of course is whatever your security column is called.

What you are doing here is conditionally applying row-level security based on what parameter your user has selected.